# Generate polygons of city blocks from streets with higher accuracy

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap

I have a model on QGIS that enumerate all the blocks within 1km radius with the use of Polygonize tool and OSM street data (downloaded from Geofabrik). However, the space between some wide streets/avenues are being counted as blocks. I painted some of them blue for reference. I tried to use Dissolve tool to remove these or join them with the closest 'neighbour', but it didn't work.

[image: Example]

Comment: you can look at the length vs width ratio to detect them, with a max threshold on the width (ex: must be less than 10 meters wide)

Comment: where can I select polygons according to their widths? and is it possible to join these small polygons with their closest neighbours?